# Using docker in adminer I do not see imported data

Tags: postgresql, docker

I created docker container with postgres and adminer with options:

```
lprods_db:
    image: postgres:9.6.10-alpine
    ports:
        - '5433:5432'
    restart: always
    environment: 
        POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '1'
        POSTGRES_DB: 'wprods'
    volumes:
        - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/


lprods_adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 8083:8080
    links:
        - lprods_db
```

I need to upload my dump into wprods db of my lprods_db instance
I run in console of my OS :

```
cat  /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/lprods/__SQL/wprods_2017_10_23.sql   | docker exec -i   lprods_docker_lprods_db_1    psql -Upostgres
```

where 
/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/lprods/__SQL/wprods_2017_10_23.sql  is sql dump in my OS path
and
lprods_docker_lprods_db_1 - db container

I saw long output of commands of postgres importing data without errors, like :

```
CREATE INDEX
ALTER TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
ALTER TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
REVOKE
REVOKE
GRANT
GRANT
```

By opening adminer at http://127.0.0.1:8083/ I did not find any tables in specified db : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLWVT.jpg
I expected my data would be imported into wprods.public. Is it so?
What is wrong?

Are there some FLUSH command could be used here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're accessing the database in a docker container and not your local one?

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK #2:

Comment: Please the command you used to create the dump, it's important

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `docker-compose.yml` and the commands you use seem fully correct - I started up everything at first try.

The only seeming pitfall here is that `pg_dump`'s output doesn't know anything about the database name. From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html):

> Script dumps are plain-text files containing the SQL commands
>   required to reconstruct the database

So when you restore it via `psql` you need to explicitly specify the target database name, in your case the command would look like

```
cat /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/lprods/__SQL/wprods_2017_10_23.sql | docker exec -i lprods_docker_lprods_db_1 psql -Upostgres wprods
```

otherwise you'll populate the default `postgres` database